# Insert Error Logs on registration failures to a table in PHP

Tags: php, database, error-handling, error-log

I am modifying a system, where I need to add error log on registration failures when existing e-mail found, existing National Identity card(NIC) found and in captcha failures. To insert error log records, going to use the table z_error_log. I think this need to be done in the "else" part of the Vendor_cont.php file. Currently this provides an error messgae if an existing e-mail is used. I need to send that error log to the db.
 This is the code and I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.
=================Vendor.php============

```
public function register_vendor(){
    //Function Body
}
```

========Log_model.php============

```
 public function createErrorLog($user,$function,$error_data,$data){

        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $browser_os=  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $data= (array) $data_obj;

    //print_r($data);

    if (is_array($data)) {
        $val = '(' . implode(',', array_keys($data)) . ')';
        $val .= '=(' . implode(',', $data) . ')';
    } else {
        $val = $data;
    }

    $oStmt= $this->oDb->prepare('INSERT INTO z_error_log (`row_id`,`user`,`ip`,`page`,`function`,`data`,`browser_os`) VALUES (:row_id,:user,:ip,:page,:function,:data,:browser_os)');
    $oStmt->bindParam(':row_id', $row_id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $oStmt->bindParam(':user', $user, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $oStmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $oStmt->bindParam(':page', $page1, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $oStmt->bindParam(':function', $page_url, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $oStmt->bindParam(':data', $val, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $oStmt->bindParam(':browser_os', $browser_os, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $oStmt->execute();

    return  $this->oDb->lastInsertId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no try catch block in your code, But you can use it like this

```
public function register_vendor(){
    try{
        //Your logic
    }catch(Exception $exception){
        //Then in here you can get the error message and save it into db
            echo $exception->getMessage();
            echo $exception->getLine();
            echo $exception->getCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my code you see commented //Your Logic just replace that comment with your entire code, then make a mistake/error and you will seeing the magic ;)

Comment: did you see the error message  as output including the line number, code and message itself?

Comment: I add an existing e-mail address. But it displays the error message which is already there.